# Comment delete is sending a get request instead a delete one

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

When I try to delete a comment, it sends a get request instead of a delete one.
When the `before_action :correct_User, only: [:destroy]` is active, it shows the error ***Unauthorized to delete the comment*** although the user connected is the same who created the comment.

***comments controller*** :

```
class CommentsController < ApplicationController

  #before_action :correct_User, only: [:destroy]

  def new
    @comment = current_user.comments.new
  end


  def create
    @comment = current_user.comments.new(comment_params)

    if @comment.save
      redirect_to post_comments_path
    else
      flash.now[:notice] = "Couldn't create the comment!"
    end
  end


  def destroy
    @comment = current_user.comments.find(params[:id])

    @comment.comments.destroy_all
    if @comment.destroy
      redirect_to post_comments_path
    else
      redirect_to post_comments_path
      flash[:notice] = "Couldn't delete the comment!"
    end
  end


  private

  def correct_User
    @comment = current_user.comments.find_by(id: params[:id])
    redirect_to post_comments_path, notice: "You are not authorized to delete this comment!" if @comment.nil?
  end

  def comment_params
    params.require(:comment).permit(:content, :parent_id).merge(post_id: params[:post_id])
  end
end
```

***routes.rb*** :

```
Rails.application.routes.draw do
  #get 'posts/index'
  resources :posts do
    resources :comments, only: [:create, :destroy]
  end

  resources :likes, only: [:destroy, :create]

  resources :sessions, only: [:create, :destroy]
  get 'sessions/new'
  get 'sing_in', to: 'sessions#new'
  delete 'sign_out', to: 'sessions#destroy'

  resources :users, only: [:create, :destroy]
  get 'users/new'
  get '/register', to: 'users#new'

  root 'posts#index'
end
```

***_comment.html.erb*** in the comments views :

```
<article>

  <p><strong>@<%= comment.user.username %></strong></p>
  <!-- HERE WE ARE REFERENCING THE COMMENT MODEL WITH THE COMMENT DATATYPE IN THE DB-->
  <p class="comment-body">
    <%= comment.content%>
  </p>

  <!-- TODO: CHECK OUT WHY THE DELETE FUNCTION AIN'T WORKING-->
  <% if current_user.id == comment.user_id %>
    <%= button_to 'Delete', post_comment_path(comment), method: :delete %>
  <%end %>

  <a href="#" class="comment-form-display">Reply</a>
  <div class="reply-sub-comment">
    <%= render partial: 'comments/format', locals: {post: comment.post, parent: comment} %>
  </div>

  <hr />
  <div class="sub-comment">
    <%= render comment.comments %>
  </div>


</article>


</div>

<script>
  document.querySelectorAll('.comment-form-display').forEach((el) => {
      el.addEventListener('click', (ev) => {
          ev.preventDefault();
          el.nextElementSibling.style = 'display: block;'
      })
  })
</script>

<style>
    .sub-comment {
        padding-left: 6em;
    }

    .reply-sub-comment {
        display: none;
    }
</style>
```

***Request's details*** :
Request URL: http://localhost:3000/posts/27/comments
Request Method: GET
Status Code: 404 Not Found
Remote Address: [::1]:3000
Referrer Policy: strict-origin-when-cross-origin

So I've tried to comment the before_action out, yet it ain't helped, pressing the delete button simply sends a get request and refresh the page.

Comment: Are you sure Rails UJS (Turbo these days) is running client-side?

Comment: That style and scripting code belongs in `application.css` and `application.js` respectively.

Comment: Pardon my question, but how can I make sure that the UJS is running the client side?

Comment: Try replacing `method: :delete` with `data: { "turbo-method": :delete }`

Comment: I added the ```data: {"turbo-method": :delete}``` tho it ain't helped. It keeps sending a get request

Comment: i think the `post_comment_path(comment)` will not generate the url like `posts/27/comments` , so i assume it should be `post_comments_path(comment)` with `s`.  However, the `post_comments_path` should not be the delete path, it should be `post_comment_path(post, comment), method: :delete`.